# Rails ActiveModel: inheritance namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, model

I have a parent class

```
class Project::Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
```

And two inherited classes

```
class Project::Loan::Subscription < Project::Subscription
class Project::Investment::Subscription < Project::Subscription
```

When I call `Project::Loan::Subscription.first`, it shows:

```
  Project::Loan::Subscription Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "project_subscriptions".* FROM "project_subscriptions" WHERE "project_subscriptions"."type" IN ('Project::Loan::Subscription')  ORDER BY "project_subscriptions"."id" ASC LIMIT
```

Which is correct.

But when I call `Project::Investment::Subscription.first`, it shows:

```
Project::Subscription Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "project_subscriptions".* FROM "project_subscriptions"  ORDER BY "project_subscriptions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

In the last call, `Project::Investment::Subscription` is acting like `Project::Subscription`

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: post the rest of the source

Comment: My interpretation was that Rails did not prepend table names depending on class inheritance. Are you setting the able names explicitly?

Comment: @RichPeck No i'm not setting table names explicitly.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot The rest of code source are just methods. I'm not overwriting table names.